# What is the default debug port for WebLogic?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, weblogic-10.x

`WebLogic` default running port is `7001`, so what is default debug port, or is it the same as running port?

I have deployed an application on `WebLogic`, now I am able to access it through url - http://localhost:7001/myapp

Now I am setting debug mode in `Eclipse`. What I need to give as debug port there?

Answer (score 5):

The default port of weblogic 12.1.3 is **8453**

Answer (score 3):

Edit

**weblogic_home_directory/bin/setDomainEnv.sh** file and add this on top &
configure debug port for weblogic

```
DEBUG_PORT=${DEBUG_PORT:=8000} 
JAVA_OPTIONS="$JAVA_OPTIONS -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=$DEBUG_PORT,server=y,suspend=n"
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

There is no default debug port for Weblogic, while starting weblogic you need to add the following parameter to the startup script.

```
-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=4001
```

And you can specify any `port` on the `address`, then you can use this port (e.g 4000) from eclipse for remote debugging.

Comment: I  am running weblogic through GUI

Comment: And how it has taken 7001 fur running deployed application?

Comment: I have a question ,do we need a debug port or we can give 7001 to the eclipse where I am configuring debug mode

Comment: please admise me how to run above command,or can we do this from GUI?